# grep on remote machine

Tags: ssh, grep, remote

I have a template file with content

count : 2

```
ssh ubuntu@ip << EOF
 cat template|grep count|awk -F":" '{print $2}' > log
EOF
```

Desired output is 2

but it's printing `count : 2`

Comment: 1) You don't need `cat`. 2) Add the contents of the file to your question.

Comment: What have you done to debug?

Comment: `cat template| awk '/count/ {print $2}' | ssh ubuntu@ip "cat - > log"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The here-document `<< EOF` creates a quoting context similar to `"..."` in which variables are expanded. You have a `$2` in there, which is expanded by the local shell. (The apostrophes don't quote anything because they are inside the larger quoted string (heredoc) so they are not special characters. You can't "increase the quoting level" by nesting `'...'` inside `"..."`)

Your local shell probably doesn't have a `$2` parameter, so it expands to the empty string, and what the remote shell receives on stdin is:

```
cat template|grep count|awk -F":" '{print }' > log
```

And awk `print`s the whole line.

You can ask the heredoc operator not to expand variables by adding apostrophe-style quoting to terminating string, like this:

```
ssh ... << 'EOF'
...
EOF
```

If you do that to your example, the `$2` will survive heredoc processing and be passed through ssh to the remote shell.

Additional tip: `cat | grep | awk` is doubly wasteful, since `awk`can do all that. Your remote command is equivalent to

```
awk -F":" '/count/ {print $2}' template > log
```